# Unable to use volume in docker compose yml in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, ssl, docker-compose

I have an Azure app service which is using `docker-compose.yml` file as it is multi-container docker app. It's `docker-compose.yml` file is given below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  multiapp:
    image: yogyogi/apps:i1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MultiApp/Dockerfile

  multiapi:
    image: yogyogi/apps:i2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MultiApi/Dockerfile
```

**The app works pefectly with no issues. I can open it on the browser perfectly.**

Now here starts the problem. I am trying to put an SSL Certficate for this app. I want to use volume and map it to inside the container. So i changed the docker-compose.yml file to:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  multiapp:
    image: yogyogi/apps:i1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MultiApp/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypass123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
        - SSL:/https

  multiapi:
    image: yogyogi/apps:i2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MultiApi/Dockerfile
```

Here only the following lines are added to force the app to use `aspnetapp.pfx` as the SSL. This ssl should be mount to https folder of the container.

```
environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypass123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
        - SSL:/https/aspnetapp.pfx:ro
```

Also note that here **SSL** given on the volume is referring to Azure File Share. I have created an Azure Storage account (called 'myazurestorage1') and inside it created an Azure file share (called 'myfileshare1'). In this file share I created a folder by th name of **ssl** and uploaded my certificate inside this folder.

Then in the azure app service which contains the app running in docker compose. I did path mappings for this azure file share so that it can be used with your app. In the below screenshot see this:

[image]

I also tried the following `docker-compose.yml` file as given in [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#using-azure-file-share-as-volumes-in-aci-containers) but no use:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  multiapp:
    image: yogyogi/apps:i1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MultiApp/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypass123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ./mydata/ssl/aspnetapp.pfx:/https/aspnetapp.pfx:ro

  multiapi:
    image: yogyogi/apps:i2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MultiApi/Dockerfile

volumes:
  mydata:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: myfileshare1
      storage_account_name: myazurestorage1
      storageAccountKey: j74O20KrxwX+vo3cv31boJPb+cpo/pWbSy72BdSDxp/d7hXVgEoR56FVA7B+L6D/CnmdpIqHOhiEKqbuttLZAw==
```

But this does not works as app starts getting error. What is wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: Do you try to mount the folder, not the certificate file? Maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Yes i tried mounting the folder but still no success.

Comment: Like you said in the question? And what is the error message?

Comment: error is coming as file nof found.

Comment: You need to go inside the container to see does the file exists in the mount path.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Do you solve it?

Comment: No actually it seems their is a bug on Azure. When I try to run the same volume code on "Azure Container Instances" then it run perfectly. However in Azure App Services this code does not work. Thank you @CharlesXu for your help.

Comment: It's a little different between the Azure App Service and the ACI on mounting Azure File Share. If you deploy to App Service, please take a look at the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux).

Comment: Do you solve the problem with the advice?

Comment: I moved to Azure Container Instance. As soon as I will find the time to check it I will update here. Thank you.